# python: how to plot a function for a random set of values for a variable

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to figure out how to plot a function that is dependent on a variable `k` but the values of this variable are a random selection of numbers: `1.9, 2.9, 4.3, 8.2`. I thought about using `range` but the values for `k` aren't evenly spread out - is there a way of plotting each of these on the same plot without having to rewrite my function under a letter for each value (i.e. iterate the function over the 4 values listed above)? The code I have is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k = 1.9
w0 = -0.8

a = np.linspace(0,1,1000)

w = -1.0 + (1.0 + w0)*(a**(3.0*k - 3.0))

plt.plot(a,w,'k--')
plt.axis([0,1,-1.2,-0.2])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k = [1.9, 2.9, 4.3, 8.2]
w0 = -0.8

a = np.linspace(0,1,1000)

for v in k:
    w = -1.0 + (1.0 + w0)*(a**(3.0*v - 3.0))
    plt.plot(a,w)

plt.axis([0,1,-1.2,-0.2])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```